# My algorithm needs to handle different amount of elements of csv input/output in Python

Tags: python-3.x

This algorithm can only use csv file in lists that have four elements.

However I don't know how to algorithm it if csv file got more than or less than  4 elements. I tried it in many ways and looked all of web pages but still, I got no answer.

```
infilename = input("Enter the location of your input file : ")
outfilename = input("Enter the location of your input file : ")

infile = open(infilename, "r")
outfile = open(outfilename, "w")

outfile.write("Column,Sum,Mean,STD,Median,Mode,Min,Max\n")

column = 0

for line in infile:
    if line:
        column += 1
        infileline = line.rstrip().split(",")
        infileline.sort()
        total = float(infileline[0]) + float(infileline[1]) + float(infileline[2]) + float(infileline[3])
        mean = total / 4
        std =  ((float(infileline[0])**2 + float(infileline[1])**2 + float(infileline[2])**2 + float(infileline[3])**2) / 4) - mean**2
        median = (float(infileline[1]) + float(infileline[2])) / 2
        mode = 2
        minimum = float(infileline[0])
        maximum = float(infileline[3])

        outfile.write(str(column)+',')
        outfile.write(','.join("%1.0f"%i for i in (total, mean, std, median,mode, minimum, maximum)))
        outfile.write('\n')


infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Enclose all code in "if line" in try-except statement. It will help.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose all code in "if line" in try-except statement. It will help.